# Wrong color & line Width with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift3, uibezierpath

I am having a weird trouble with UIBezierPath where my color and the line width are not being rendered correctly.

I am drawing a series of lines (like a ruler) with major and minor gradations. The major gradations are lines with longer length...

Major Gradation: Color Red & Line Width: 2.0
Minor Gradation: Color Yellow & Line Width: 0.0 (thinnest line according to spec)

[image: slider]

```swift
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
    if let _ = cameraControlSlider {
        guard gradationValues.count >= 0 else {
            return
        }

        let frame = CGRect(x: insetBy, y: 0, width: bounds.width - insetBy, height: bounds.height)
        ctx.clear(frame)

        let startx = Int(frame.origin.x)
        let endx = Int(frame.origin.x + frame.width)

        let incrementWidth = (endx - startx) / (gradationValuesOnScreen + 1)

        var counter = 1
        var x = startx + counter * incrementWidth

        while x < endx {

            var y1 = Int(frame.origin.y)
            var y2 = Int(frame.origin.y) + Int(frame.height)
            var lineWidth: Float = 2.0
            var color = UIColor.red

            if counter % majorGradationInterval != 1 {
                y1 = Int(frame.origin.y) + Int(frame.height / 4)
                y2 = Int(frame.origin.y + frame.height) - Int(frame.height / 4)
                lineWidth = 0.0
                color = UIColor.yellow
            }

            ctx.addPath(drawLine(in: ctx, x1: x, y1: y1, x2: x, y2: y2, color: color, lineWidth: lineWidth))
            counter += 1
            x = startx + counter * incrementWidth
        }
    }
}

func drawLine(in ctx: CGContext, x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int, color: UIColor, lineWidth: Float) -> CGPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    ctx.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)

    path.lineWidth = CGFloat(lineWidth)
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2))
    path.close()

    ctx.strokePath()

    return path.cgPath
}
```

Essentially I want the longer lines to be of RED color and thicker line width but the colors look inverted and the line width doesn't seem to have any impact.

As can be seen from the draw function there is no UIColor red which is associated with the smaller line lengths. I have tried setting the stroke color before the path is created but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, but the key issue is that `drawLine` is creating a `UIBezierPath` and is calling `strokePath`. But `strokePath` doesn't stroke that `UIBezierPath` you just created, but rather the previous path added to that context. But since you don't add the line to the context until after you return from `drawLine`, everything is off by one. Plus, since you're adding all those lines to the context (rather than replacing the path), you're doing a bunch of redrawing of the same lines repeatedly.

You can fix it by just calling `drawLine` rather than `addPath(drawLine(...)`:

```
override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
    ...

    while x < endx {
        ...

        drawLine(in: ctx, x1: x, y1: y1, x2: x, y2: y2, color: color, lineWidth: lineWidth)

        ...
    }
}
```

And `drawLine` doesn't return anything, but actually just draws it:

```
func drawLine(in ctx: CGContext, x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int, color: UIColor, lineWidth: Float) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    ctx.saveGState()
    ctx.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    ctx.setLineWidth(CGFloat(lineWidth))
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2))
    ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)
    ctx.strokePath()
    ctx.restoreGState()
}
```

Note, I'm saving and restoring the graphical context so that I can draw new line line segment path each time. Also, since I'm stroking the context's path, I'm calling `setLineWidth` on the context, not the path. Also, not shown here, I found that if I stroked the yellow lines with a width of zero, they didn't appear, so I used 1:

[image: example image]

Note, if this were a `UIView` subclass you could simplify this further (just stroke the `UIBezierPath` directly rather than messing around with CoreGraphics, you could make it `@IBDesignable`, etc.). But if you're going to implement `draw(in:)`, I'd probably do something like the above.

Comment: That was perfect @Rob. It makes sense. However, you mentioned that it's redrawing since we add to the context. Wouldn't that still happen with the changes you mentioned above along with saving the G state. Also, when do you use path.stroke vs ctx.stroke. Path.stroke was giving me errors with invalid context that's why I didn't use it. The UIView approach sounds interesting. I have to try it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Re redrawing, because we're saving and restoring the context, the path gets reset to it's prior path-less state (e.g. save context, add path, stroke it, and restore it to path-less state, and repeat).

Comment: Re `path.stroke`, you use that when you're already in a graphics context (e.g. in the `draw(_ rect:)` of a `UIView` subclass). I really like the `UIView` subclass approach, because the code is simpler, you can just add it to a view hierarchy like any other `UIView`, and if, if appropriate, make it `@IBDesignable`, and see it right in your storyboard. But you might have enough written around the `draw(in:)` pattern that that's more work than needed. Fortunately, both approaches work fine.